# Software to monitor system calls?

Tags: api, system-monitor, process-control

I am currently working on a project, it would be helpful if I could monitor what happens inside the OS when I run an application or when I press some shortcut key.

more precisely, I would like to know internally what systems calls are made by a process ( an instance of an application ), its PID, etc.

I would like to get the above information for both applications as well as for shortcut keys:-

ex:-

1. if firefox is running right now, whats the process ID? what system calls has it made?
2. if I press alt+tab, what system calls have been made?

I have tried using process monitor, windows performance analyzer, but i don't see how the above can be done using those apps.

Comment: I think the answer will be highly OS-dependent, please specify the OS.

Comment: As of now, I'm interested in windows and ubuntu.

Comment: Welcome pal!  Because answers to your question will likely be OS-dependent, can you please specify a single OS in your question, and tag appropriately?  Feel free to write additional question (even if it is mostly cut and paste) for another operating system.  Thanks!